# Connection much slower over TCP Socket then Telnet

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, outputstream

I am trying to send commands to an ESP8266 over a local network. The ESP processes the command to turn for example a light on. The code of the ESP is irrelevant here. My problem is that the response time over my Android App is much higher then using telnet on the same phone (app = 2 seconds, telnet = nearly immediately). I am not sure if the problem is the chosen method to write the data or my method to implement the thread (see the code). I tried different StreamWriters (BufferedOutputstream etc) and also to priories the thread, but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

```
public class NetworkController extends Thread {

private static final String HOST = "192.168.178.69";
private static final int PORT = 50344;
public  boolean isAlive;
public  boolean connected = true;
public MainActivity main;
public Socket client;
private DataInputStream input;
private BufferedOutputStream output;
private BufferedWriter outputWriter;

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        client = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
        input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(client != null) {
        isAlive = true;
        System.out.println("Is Connected");
        while (connected) {
            if (!MainActivity.commandQueue.isEmpty()) {
                String command = MainActivity.commandQueue.poll();
                command += "\n";
                try {
                    output.write(command.getBytes());

                    output.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    isAlive = false;
    System.out.println("Thread is not reachable for some Reason");

}
```

}

Despite the fact that my code is not safe for use as it is right now, a short explanation: If someone clicks a certain button it adds the command to the commandQueue which is constantly checked in this Thread.

EDIT: I did some test and monitored the ESP as well. The problem is definitely the outputWriter. The thread responds immediately, the ESP is getting the first data-bytes immediately as well, but the whole package (just short Strings) takes much longer to transmit then over a telnet connection. Any idea to use fast methods to write data over an output stream?

Comment: You are spin-looping. Remove the `isEmpty()` test, so you will block in `poll()`.

Comment: Due to the documentation `poll()`won't block, instead set the `command` variable to null. I changed the code so the if-Statement checks for the result of the `poll()` instead of checking the queue, but it still takes nearly two to three seconds for the ESP to respond.

Comment: `The code of the ESP is irrelevant here.`. Dont think so. How big is the message you send?

Comment: The message is just a dozen characters long tops, such as `Light1On` or similar to that. 
The code of the ESP seems irrelevant because it is clearly working with the telnet connection and there is nothing I could change due to the limited options in C librarys realizing a TCP Server on an ESP :(

Comment: Dont use a buffered writer or stream.

Comment: @greenapps any recommendations? I thought using BufferedWriter is the fastest way for that?

Comment: Well did you meanwhile try without?

Comment: Yes.. just used `client.getOutputStream().write(command.getBytes())` ... didn't worked :/

Comment: So change `poll()` to `take()`. That blocks. Which is the point of the exercise.

Comment: Try to disable Nagle's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).